# multiple url opener in html and javascript not working on blogger

Tags: javascript, html

It doesn't open multiple urls but single http url can open and https url 
   not opening.  Please advise me.

This is javascript code:

```
<script>function open_all(){
var urls = document.getElementById("list_urls").value;
var urls = urls.split('\n');
var totalno = urls.length;
var s;
for(var i=0;i<totalno;i++){
s = urls[i];
if(s){
if(s.substr(0,7)!='http://') s = 'http://'+s;
window.open(s);
}
}
return false;
}
</script>
```

This is HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<br />
<textarea name="list_urls" id="list_urls" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea>
<br /><br />
<input value="Open URLs" class="submit" type="button" onclick="open_all();" /><br /><input type="reset" value="Reset!" /><br/></form>
```

Comment: Can you add the exact value of that textarea that you're testing with?

Comment: what does the return false do?

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly. You need to at least show some sample input, and _properly_ describe what "not working" actually means.

Comment: `and https url not opening` - well _of course_ that can't work this way, because you prefix _everything_ that does not start with `http://` _exactly_ already, with an additional `http://` - and trying to open `http://https://example.com/` is obviously nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

What's the issue here? As a single code block on the DOM your code setup works precisely as it sounds like you want it to...

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <br>
  <textarea name="list_urls" id="list_urls" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input value="Open URLs" class="submit" type="button" onclick="open_all();">
  <br>
  <input type="reset" value="Reset!">
  <br>
</form>

<script>
  function open_all() {
    var urls = document.getElementById("list_urls").value;
    var urls = urls.split('\n');
    var totalno = urls.length;
    var s;
    for (var i = 0; i < totalno; i++) {
      s = urls[i];
      if (s) {
        if (s.substr(0, 7) != 'http://') s = 'http://' + s;
        window.open(s);
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
</script>
```